# Merging Arabic + English Text

Tags: c++, text, unicode, merge, arabic

I'm trying to save in the xml field text which consists from Arabic and English letters. The problem is - my string looks like this:

```
هذا هو الاختبار test
```

But when I try to display that string, I'm having this:

```
test هذا هو الاختبار
```

I know that I should put correct unicode characters there, but I can't find proper combination of it for the case when Arabic letters are going first. For example, when I was having English word + Arabic word, I managed to keep that order with current combination:

```
0x202a; test 0x202b; هذا هو الاختبار
```

Note :(instead of `0x` I was using `&#x` , I just put it that way because stackoverflow is hiding them)

With those combination of Unicode characters (`0x202a` and `0x202b`) my string isn't reshuffling. But it seems like it's not so easy to pick right unicode characters for the different case.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between your text and how is displayed. Different 'rendering engines' may render the text (handle the RTL business) in different ways. Said in other terms your sentence 'try to display my string' is rather vague...

Comment: Unicode will be part of the answer, but for now it's completely unclear how you store your source text and what encoding is used behind the scenes.

Comment: Hello grek40! I told that I store my source text in xml format, and I'm not using any encoding whatsoever. That's up for OS. Btw, unicodes I provided work both on Windows and Linux

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev well then start using some encoding right now! You can't just expect the OS to handle those things when dealing with multiple languages. Doesn't your XML start with a declaration line like for example `<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>`? Well at least it should and the encoding of the whole XML file better match with the specified encoding from the declaration!

Comment: In case you didn't read this or a similar article already: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @grek40 Hello! Thank you for your answer. I didn't understand your first answer about encoding correctly, I think I missread it. Of course I'm using encoding tag in xml, it's standard `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: I think I pointed out that it's not a problem of encoding. Encoding is about understanding of what symbol should be shown and of course encoding has its own rules of showing text content. But the problem is that sometimes those rules should be avoided like in my case (Arabic + English in one string). And this task should be accomplished by inserting special characters combination which I successfully found for "English+Arabic" case, but not for "Arabic+English"

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev actually, encoding has no rule of showing text content, so you really have to explain everything in your question. Since you declare UTF-8 in the XML header, did you make sure that the file is actually stored in UTF-8 encoding? With or without BOM? When you say *"try to display that string"*, where and how do you display it exactly? There shouldn't be such thing as a combination of unicode characters... just a combination of bytes that form an UTF-8 encoded unicode codepoint (or whatever it is called)